# are push notifications better than sockets when mobile is moving

Tags: android, ios, sockets, push-notification

I need to send some data to my client, and I want to know if using push notifications is better than using sockets.

I heard some say that sockets are not good because they can stop working if the mobile phone is changing it's IP(anyway how often does this happen).

How reliable are sockets> when would you rather go for push notifications?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Push notifications are for:

-When you want to send information to the device that the user didn't request first (generally a ping that there's new data on the server that the user will want to download)

-When there's no guarantee that the application is running.

Sockets are for:

-When the application is running - Aka, user clicks on something they want to download, data is sent via socket.

Also, on Android, push notifications max out at 4K of data, because (as previously mentioned) they're only really meant to notify, not to transmit large amounts of data.  For that you'll need to use sockets anyway.  Furthermore, you'll need to deal with the fact that  sockets *do* stop sending data for a variety of reasons - The user hops wifi networks, goes through a tunnel, drives through an area with spotty reception, etc, etc.

Comment: actually it's 4kb of payload data.  Source: http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gcm.html#registering

Comment: You're correct, but at the time of the writing the push notification system was C2DM, not GCM.  C2DM had a 1K max.  GCM bumped it up to 4K :)

Answer (score 2):

Push notifications can be used both while the application is n the background and while it is in the foreground, but they are not nearly as reliable as sockets.

Generally a good solution is to use both. You can respond to a push notification while the application is open by refreshing your sockets or by polling the server. I would avoid relying exclusively on push notifications though. Just use them when your app is closed.

Comment: how reliable are sockets on Android or iOS? when would they crash? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Push notifications are to be used when your app is not running and along with UILocalNotifications are the only way to send information to the app when it is is not running.

Comment: how reliable do you find sockets? do you recommend sockets over long polling?

Answer (score 1):

> I heard some say that sockets are not good because they can stop working if the mobile phone is changing it's IP(**anyway how often does this happen**).

I can give you what is admittedly not a usual scenario...

My local pub provides free wi-fi. So I'm having a drink with friends and my phone automatically connects to the pub wi-fi. Once I leave the pub and I'm out of range, if I have mobile internet enabled, my phone will connect to my provider's data network.

On the way home I stop in my local corner shop to pick up some groceries. I set-up the wi-fi for the owners' residence above the shop sometime back and my phone is configured to remember their wi-fi connection details so it connects. I leave the shop, go out of range and my phone connects to my provider's data network again.

I decide I'd like Chinese food tonight and stop in the take-away near my house. I also set-up their wi-fi system for them and my phone automatically connects to their access-point. I leave the shop and my phone connects to my provider's data network.

I get home and my phone then connects to my own wi-fi network.

So in a distance of about 400 yards (~300 metres), my phone will have changed connection state 6 different times.

Sorry to be a bit verbose but that IS a real-world scenario - my business is to provide IT support to private and small-business users.

In other words, whatever your app does, you need to cater for the fact that networks on mobile technology can change multiple times and you need to monitor the change of state and, if necessary, tear-down and re-create existing connections.

A direct socket connection may well be more immediate put requires extra handling for network changes. Push notifications have the advantage of being asynchronous assuming the push-server is set-up right.

Comment: Are the extra handling for network changes worth it though? I wonder if this has improved in 5 years.